# Compiling Jade with Grunt to a specific directory

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, gruntjs, pug

I'm trying to compile Jade files to HTML and put them in a directory.
Currently when I compile, the created HTML files are going into the right directory but they are within a created directory called jade.

Here is my directory structure:

- jade
- html

But after compile it looks like this:

- jade
- html/jade

Ideally I just want the HTML files to go into the html directory and not within a jade directory.

Here is the relevant part of my gruntfile:

```
jade: {
  compile: {
      files: [{
          expand: true,
          src: ['jade/**/*.jade'],
          dest: 'html/',
          ext: '.html'
      }]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output structure mirrors the `src` option. Try the `cwd` option.

Refer to: http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically

Example:

```
jade: {
  compile: {
      files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'jade/',
          src: ['**/*.jade'],
          dest: 'html/',
          ext: '.html'
      }]
   }
}
```